# How to use find method for composite primary keys in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a table called `SubElement`.

It has two primary keys : `Element_Code, Sub_Element_Code`

In my view, when i try to do something like the following

```
<% 
  sub_element_model = Condition::SubElement
  sub_element = @sub_element_code.nil? ? sub_element_model.new : sub_element_model.find(@sub_element_code)
  if sub_element.persisted?
    @element_code = sub_element.Element_Code
    f.object.Sub_Element_Code = @sub_element_code
  end
%>
```

I got an error after selected the sub_element_value like

```
["4"]: Incorrect number of primary keys for Condition::SubElement: [:Element_Code, :Sub_Element_Code]
```

How can i use the find method for two composite primary keys.

### Update:

In the form, I have `element_code field, sub_element_code and material`. But everything should visible once the parent selected. With the help of some javascript I try to finish this. The Main problem of what I could not explain in detail is the form fields are creating by some helper file. It's a very large file and i cant change that. So I am looking for the alternative solution to change the find method for the two composite primary keys to get the value.

Comment: It has two primary keys??

Comment: Yeah. It has two primary keys of `Element_Code, Sub_Element_Code`

Comment: I think you meant a primary key with two attributes - en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_key

Comment: @fotanus the problem is I can't change anything.

Comment: Can you explain what you are attempting to do in this view?  It's not self-explanatory to say the least...

Comment: @PinnyM the problem isn't the view, it is the find method. "How to use find method..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be using `find` (which gets a single record by primary key - which you don't completely have), but rather `where` (which gets you a collection of records by any field(s) you want):

```
sub_element = @sub_element_code ? 
    SubElement.where(sub_element_code: @sub_element_code).first : 
    SubElement.new
```

Comment: Now, I got undefined method persisted?

Comment: Probably because no `SubElement` was found with that `sub_element_code`.  Is it supposed to lookup by the `element_code` field or the `sub_element_code` field?

Comment: It should lookup the both field. :-(

Comment: When doing the lookup, what variable should it use for `element_code`, and what variable for `sub_element_code`?

Comment: Thank you Pinny. I changed the javascript to find the variable for the element_code and sub_element_code and its working now with your `where` method. Thank you so much. I really appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to do with the code above but you could use `where`:

```
sub_element_model.where(first_id: 3, second_id: 5).first
```

Your code doesn't look very conventional-ish however, perhaps if you described what you're trying to do SOers could help you come up with a neater solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I myself never try using a multiple attribute primary key, but I believe that ActiveRecord is telling you that you are not using the correct number of primary keys in your `find` search.

Try something like

```
Model.find([first_part_of_primary_key, second_part_of_primary_key])
```

Comment: this answer is most effectible.